# Is $p_1$ always $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Shilov's Linear Algebra. In the red marking:

> [image]

I'm a bit confused, doesn't that imply $p_1$ is always $1$? But previously, when he says that "we can find vectors $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_{p_1}$", it seems that $p_1$ shouldn't always be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect, so let me correct it. Instead, Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A^2=0$. Now, let $e_i$ be the $i$th coordinate vector. Then $Ae_1=0$, $Ae_2=e_1$, $Ae_3=0$ and $Ae_4=e_3$. This means that $H_1=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,e_3\}$ is $2$-dimensional (so $m_1=2$) and $H_2=K^4$ is $4$ dimensional (so $m_2=4$). Now, $p_1=m_2-m_1=2$. This gives an example where $p_1\neq 1$.

Comment: I'm still confused, isn't $p_1$ the index of one vectors in the basis of $H_r$? Also, he still didn't mention matrices in Jordan form, it will be further in this section.

Comment: Yes, but how doesn't that mean that $p_1=1$? Perhaps my problem is the following: I am considering we have all the subspaces $H_0, H_1, \dots, H_r$. Perhaps he is talking about some particular collection such as $H_5, H_{34}, H_{71}$. Is that is?

Comment: What is $E_{23}$? I never heard nor read about that terminology.

Comment: I guess this is what was missing. We "solve" first for $p_1$ and then find the rest wrt this. I thought it was the other way arround. But then, what does $m_r - m_{r-1}$ reveal to us?

Comment: I've seen it. I guess I get it, $p_1$ is the height of the highest basis vector (supposing it exists) and this number equals the other side of the equality. Does it make sense?

Comment: I guess I figured out. Suppose we take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}&{1}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}
\end{pmatrix}$$ then $A^2=0$. Suppose we have the cannonical basis on $R^4$, call it $X$, and define:

$$H_i=\{x\in X \mid B^ix=0\}$$

Then:
 
 $$H_1=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\} \\H_2=H_3=H_4= \{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$$

I'm a bit confused here: As $H_4=H_3=H_2$, then $p_1=m_2 - m_{1}=4-3=1$. Is that correct? I'm confused because it seems we're trying to construct a basis for $H_1$ and we would need $3$ vectors, no?